# Install mysql 5.5 without remove old version

Tags: mysql, database

I am using `CentOS 5.7 (64-bit)`. By default `mysql 5.0.88` version is installed in my machine. Now i wants to install `mysql 5.5`, without remove mysql 5.0.88. I didn't get any clear document to install a new version without remove the old one. Please share your views if you come across the same.

Answer (score 0):

Don't install non official software, least of all software from sources, unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Why do you believe you need another version of MySQL? The software versions that are officially supported by the distribution were selected and tuned to work well together. SIde-by-side installation of stuff like a RDBMS can't be simple, even in the best case. And if there aren't distribution-sanctioned packages for doing so, the chances for you getting it right are slim to none.